# what happens to unused memory in C++

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, memory-management, linked-list

I was going through some practice coding problems , and i came across one -

> Implement an algorithm to delete a node in the middle of a single linked list, 
>   given only access to that node.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>      Input: the node ‘c’ from the linked list `a->b->c->d->e`
>      Result: nothing is returned, but the new linked list looks like `a->b->d->e`

The solution to this is to simply copy the data from the next node into this node and then
delete the next node.

The above solution is keeping java in mind, as the programming language.
I am wondering what would happen to the content of deleted node? Will its fate be different in java and c++?
And also, i think the perfect answer to this question should also deallocate the memory of the deleted node. How do we do that in c++?

Comment: For C++, everyone is either saying "use `delete`" or in one case "use `delete` or `free`". In order to release memory *you have to know how it was allocated*, so for the problem to be complete, it pretty much has to tell you how to release the memory. Since it's left unknown in the question, I think a perfect answer either should mention that we don't know how to release the node, or should provide the complete list definition and implementation, including allocation. If the question is one in a series, perhaps you're expected to have already done the latter in previous questions.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Please elaborate what do you mean by 'how it was allocated'? You mean on stack or heap?

Comment: I mean using `new`, `malloc`, or some custom allocator. In the case of a custom allocator, perhaps the memory pool that it allocates from happens to be on the stack, but that's not really the important point. Or you could create an automatic ("on the stack") array of list nodes, then link them together into a list, then remove one of them from the list. In that case you'd just do nothing, and it will be released along with the rest of them when they go out of scope. There are a lot of ways to get memory in C++, and hence a lot of ways to release it.

Comment: I think what Steve is saying is that list management should be decoupled from memory management. If the class for the nodes is written correctly the user of the nodes should not have to do both. You as the user of the list simply remove the node from the list. The node class should be written in such a way that they automatically get deleted (like in Java). Look up `Seporation of Concenrn` and `smart pointer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the memory could eventually be freed by the garbage collector. There is no guarantee of when (and therefore, if) that happens. (In practice, it will usually happen very quickly).

In C++ with smart pointers, the deallocation of memory is guaranteed as soon as the object cannot be addressed anymore. In effect, it works pretty much like garbage collection in Java as long as you don't have any circular reference graphs.

If you are not using smart pointers, you'll have to manually call `delete c` (or `free(c)`). If you don't do this, your program will have allocated memory it can never use again.

Comment: Seeing delete in C++ code is usually the result of sloppy design. I hardly  ever expect to see it in user code. The design should be using smart pointers and thus there is no need to delete the object it is implicit. This is the basic seporation of concerns principle where management of the list is seprate from management of the memory resources and when doing one task the user should not be exposed to the other.

Comment: @Martin Updated. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4):

> should also deallocate the memory of the deleted node.

Yes.

> How do we do that in c++?

With the `delete` operator.

You probably getting ahead of yourself if you're working on link lists and don't know about the `delete` operator. You don't want to skip steps when learning C or C++; it will bite your head off later.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not entirely what you do in C++. What you should do/what happens:

1. Delete the memory pointed to by `c`.
2. Copy the pointer to the memory from `d` to `c`.
3. Copy the pointer to `e` from `d` to `c`.

Now effectively we took `d` out of the list and made `c` behave like it were `d`. And finally, if `d` itself is allocated somewhere too and must be deleted seperately you delete it after 3.

Why 1? Because in Java if an object is no longer used it is automatically garbage collected. In C++ this is not the case.

Comment: I think you should first copy things, and only last delete the memory.

Comment: Paŭlo Ebermann: No. In the case something goes wrong or an exception is thrown we have made the memory inaccessible but we didn't free it.

Comment: Hmm, and now you are accessing freed memory, is this better?

Comment: Good one :) Anyway, chances of something going wrong is extremely low, after the free is done, and if you were first copying the pointers then you'd need a temporary for the old pointer that you still need to free. There ain't much difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the Question Title "What happens to unused memory in C++" the memory is marked as unallocated by the memory manager but is probably not returned to the Operating System at that point (if ever) for efficiency's sake. The deallocation is made via the **delete** keyword

For your specific example (hastily cobbled together) :

Assume a node Such as

```
struct Node
{
    Node* next;
} head;   

//Later...

Node* pred = head; //Where head is the start of the list
while((pred->next != NULL) && (pred->next != c))
{
   pred  = pred->next;          
}

Node* toDelete = pred->next;
Node* newSuccessor = toDelete->next;

/*
  This is the moment when the memory is considered freed. 
  free() should only be used if the node was allocated with malloc()
*/
delete toDelete; 

pred->next = newSuccessor;
```

Comment: C++ clases should rarely if ever contain RAW pointers. Use a smart pointer. Thus I would not expect to see a delete in the code.

Comment: I agree completely and that would make a great alternative answer. If only ones expectations governed the code one actually found in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it will eventually get collected as garbage. In C++ you have to deallocate it explicitly using the `delete` keyword.

Once the memory has been freed, the actual bits will stay intact but might be reallocated and overwritten at any time.